# Manipulating properties of SVG image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to change "outline"(stroke in terms of svg properties) of my beetle after onclick button, but as I don't see any bugs in my code sample it doesn't work, why?

```
var beetlebtn=document.getElementById("btn");
var beetle =document.getElementById("Layer_1");

beetlebtn.addEventListener(click, function(){
    beetle.style.stroke="yellow";
});
```

[Link to my pen](https://codepen.io/zeeebra/pen/awqPoG)

Comment: if my answer helped please mark it as accepted

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the quotation marks around the `'click'` label, so it was just appearing as an undefined variable.

This will work

```
beetlebtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  beetle.style.stroke="yellow";
});
```

Link: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pwOWjy